# Undefined offset: 0 on for loop

Tags: php, laravel

I'm newbie in laravel. My code aim to get all selected files and save to public->upload folder.
this is my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    /**
    * @var UploadedFile
    */

    $files = $request->all();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) { 
           $file = $files[$i]->file('file');
           $file->store('upload', 'public');

    }

}
```

I have error "Undefined offset: 0". Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `var_dump($files)` or `dd($files)` to see what the array keys are. It's possible that the array is empty, or it's using different keys for the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach loop like this

```
  $files = $request->all();
    foreach ($files as $items) { 
           $file = $items->file('file');
           $file->store('upload', 'public');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isset() to check whether its exist or not then upload.

```
$files = $request->all();
for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) { 
     if(isset($files[$i])) {
       $file = $files[$i]->file('file');
       $file->store('upload', 'public');
    }
}
```